# Python Crawler - AttributeError: Crawler instance has no attribute 'url'

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

I'm trying to learn the classes in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# *-* coding: utf-8 *-*

import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

class Crawler:

    def visit(self, url):
        self.request = urllib2.Request(self.url)
        self.response = urllib2.urlopen(self.request)
        return self.response.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = Crawler()
    print x.visit("http://google.com/")
```

When I try to start getting the error:

```
sigo@sarch ~/sources $ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print x.visit("http://google.com/")
  File "test.py", line 10, in visit
    self.request = urllib2.Request(self.url)
AttributeError: Crawler instance has no attribute 'url'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're saying `self.url` which is referring to the Crawler class's `url` attribute, which does not exist.  You need to use just `url` since that's the name of the variable from your `visit()` function arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the edits!  It is indeed the `url` attribute of the class instance (i.e. `self.url`) which does not exit and the function local variable `url` which does.